# Unable to download old version of mongo DB on ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to install an old version of mongo inside a docker container like below but I hit some errors that I can't understand. I have seen other answers to this problem on other SO threads but I am not able to understand what the solutions being proposed are and some answers might be dated. How do I understand the root cause of this error?

```
root@local:/# apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir 
/tmp/tmp.XQbbbvRIBI --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring 
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver 
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 7F0CEB10: public key "Totally Legit Signing Key <mallory@example.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
root@local:/# echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
root@local:/# apt-get update
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Get:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:2 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:3 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:4 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [532 kB]
Get:5 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist InRelease
Get:6 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [6444 B]
Get:7 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [288 kB]
Get:8 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [1460 kB]
Get:9 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [21.4 kB]
Get:10 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [671 kB]
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist InRelease                 Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/downloads-distro.mongodb.org_repo_ubuntu-upstart_dists_dist_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: GPG error: http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

Comment: https://github.com/p-mongo/mongodb-faq#reference-mongodb-documentation

Comment: Sorry I am still not able to understand. Is that link to provide some missing info in the question or is it a pointer to an answer?

Comment: MongoDB has extensive documentation. Installation on ubuntu is covered in that documentation. If you are following this documentation, reference it and say where you are having problems. If you are not following it, follow it.

Comment: What is your specific Ubuntu version, what version of MongoDB are you trying to install, and what guide are you following? It looks like you are trying to use an expired signing key which has been replaced by a generic one ("Totally legit signing key" is definitely not legit). If the MongoDB release you are trying to install is end-of-life, it is likely that the release package will no longer be verifiable (and possibly no longer available in the original repo). If you can also include more details on your goal (e.g. "need to restore an old backup"), there may be a better approach to suggest.